# Find the 2nd element of array

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, instance-methods, splat

I don't understand how this isn't working. The program is supposed to take instance method second in the class Array and return the 2nd object in the array

```
class Array
  def second(*arr)
  arr.length <= 1 ? nil : arr[1]
  end
end

#Test cases
Test.assert_equals(Array([1, 2, 3]), 2,) #Getting nil
Test.assert_equals(Array([]), nil) #passes
Test.assert_equals(Array([1]), nil) #passes
```

What am I doing wrong? if I remove class Array and test on second it works fine?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are calling the method `second` anywhere.

Comment: So how would I do that cause what I've tried so far just keeps saying NoMethodError

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use `*arr`? If you're monkey-patching `Array`, then use `self`:

```
class Array
  def second
    self.length <= 1 ? nil : self[1]
  end
end

p [1,2,3].second #=> 2
p [1].second #=> nil
p [].second #=> nil
```

Comment: That worked. I didn't really know what self was. I'm pretty new to Ruby and brand new to Ruby's class notation haha
Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, I've seen you ask several questions here, and if you find a particular answer useful, it's a good practice to accept it by clicking on the check box on the left.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to what you're doing wrong, your code as written doesn't need the splat (`*`) operator (it also doesn't need to be patched into the `Array` class). While patching into `Array` and using `self` allows you to call it like `[1,2].second`, you could also write it as follows without patching into `Array`:

```
def second(arr)
  arr.length <= 1 ? nil : arr[1]
end
```

Which would need to be called like `second([1,2])`.

To find out more about the splat operator `*`, try something like [this explanation](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) (I confess - the first Google result, but seems ok), but what it's doing in your example is turning your passed-in array into an array of an array - e.g. `[1,2,3]` becomes `[[1,2,3]]`.

Comment: It was a requirement that method second be defined inside class Array. The skeleton class Array; end was given